# Ocelot throwing error in .NET 8 microservice project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ocelot

I am working on a micro service application - a simple online shop. I am learning micro services and want to use Ocelot as my gateway project, but I have a problem in the project.

Right now this is the `ocelot.json` file I use where I configured the routes:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    //"ProductAPI": "https://localhost:7000",
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "DELETE" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/productAPI",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },

    //"CouponAPI": "https://localhost:7001",
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI/GetByCode/{code}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI/GetByCode/{code}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "DELETE" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/couponAPI",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },

    //"ShoppingCartAPI": "https://localhost:7003",
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/GetCart/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/GetCart/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/RemoveCart",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/RemoveCart",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/CartUpsert",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/CartUpsert",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/EmailCartRequest",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/EmailCartRequest",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/ApplyCoupon",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/cartAPI/ApplyCoupon",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },

    //"OrderAPI": "https://localhost:7004",
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrders?userId={id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrders/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrders?userId=''",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrders/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrder/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/GetOrder/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/UpdateOrderStatus/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/UpdateOrderStatus/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/ValidateStripeSession",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/ValidateStripeSession",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/CreateStripeSession",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/CreateStripeSession",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/CreateOrder",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/orderAPI/CreateOrder",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer"
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7777"
  }
}
```

This is the `program.cs` file:

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using Shop.GatewayProject.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddAppAuthentication();

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseOcelot().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

app.Run();
```

The `appsettings.json` is basic.

Error:

> warn: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HMVPEQ365DJH:00000001, previousRequestId: No PreviousRequestId, message: 'DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /, verb: GET.'
>
> warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HMVPEQ365DJH:00000001, previousRequestId: No PreviousRequestId, message: 'Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /, verb: GET. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/, request method: GET'

I tried checking the routes and all seems fine. In the `BaseUrl` I have the gateway projects url.

I tried to keep only one route that I know would work for sure but still couldn't manage to fix it.

Comment: *I tried to keep only one route that I know would work for sure but still couldn't manage to fix it.* - please can you edit your question and remove all but the one route in your ocelot config which still exhibits this error. There are like 20 routes in your config, it's not very easy to read.

Comment: `Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /, verb: GET.'` - it looks like you tried to `GET /` but you don't have any upstream configuration for `GET /`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the error, its the ***warning***

```
warn: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
    requestId: 0HMVPEQ365DJH:00000001, previousRequestId: No PreviousRequestId, message: 'DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors. IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /, verb: GET.'
```

Setting the default route should resolve the warning as shown below

```
 {
    ......
    ......
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7000
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
      ......
      ......
```